# USB connection to Android does NOT offer an MTP choice

Tags: android, mtp

When I plug USB cable from Win-10 laptop to my HTC Nexus-9 tablet, and then tap on the resulting notification in the Android notification list, the resulting popup choice no longer offers me a choice for "MTP".  (The Android version is Nougat, aka 7.1.1)

(In the past, it WAS offering me an MTP choice, but now it offers only a std 'file-transfer' option, and a PTP photo transfer option, but NOT the MTP choice.)

What I'm trying to achieve is for it to assign a drive-letter on the Win-10 side, so that I can manage the MP3 audio files (via the Windows-cmd-shell) that I've uploaded to the tablet.

Anyone know how to get Android to once again offer me the MTP protocol option?